# Using both times and eulervm packages

Tags: fonts, packages

I'm adopting for my thesis times new roman as text font and eulervm for math fonts. Which is the correct package for times to use?

Comment: `newtxmath` for math and `newtxtext` for text. `mathptmx` also does the job.

Comment: Are you sure that is a good combination? I would not recommend Times for a thesis, have a look at `LinuxLibertine` which is wider. And definitely don't mix it with `eulervm`, look at the example @HarishKumar gave, that is horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `newtxtext` for times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^{2}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use `mathptmx` but load it before `eulervm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^{2}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^{2}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```